# Control flow jumping back to other line

Tags: c++

In this code

```
void menu() {
    char name[MAXNAME];
    float a;
    char c;
    cout << "n\tnew transaction\n";
    cout << "v\tview all transactions\n\n";

    c = getchar();
    flushbuf();
    switch (c) {
    case 'N':
    case 'n':{
        cout << "What is the name? (press 'b' to go back to the menu)\n";
        fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
        replaceTrailingNl(name); // replaces trailing '\n' (from fgets) with '\0'

        if (strcasecmp(name, "b") == 0)
            menu();
        do {
            flushbuf();
            cout << "What is the amount?\n";
        } while (scanf("%f", &a) == 0);

        if (writeTransData(name, a))
            cout << "Successfully saved!\n";
        else
            cerr << "writeTransData: Error occurred\n";
        break;}
    }
}
void flushbuf()
{
    int temp;
    while ((temp = getchar()) != EOF && temp != '\n') ;
}
```

When, 'b' is typed as the answer to the "What is the name" prompt, menu() is called (which shows the menu), the menu is shown and then I press 'n' to make a new transaction. Everything goes as expected, until the `break`. After the `break` is done, I get "What is the amount?\n" asked again, and I can actually input things to it. How is this happening? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Note that in general you should not mix `c` IO with `c++` IO. You are using `c` style input `getchar` and `c++` output `cout`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: @MarkLakata: Because it is C++ code.

Comment: It is also C code. Use of fixed char arrays, getchar, fgets, is from libc. The bug in the program is a C level bug. I understand that it won't compile with a C compiler, but the style is not strictly C or C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `menu()` again does not end the current call to `menu()`.  Call #2 will finish, and control flow will return to Call #1 and enter the `do` loop.

The simplest fix is this:

```
if (strcasecmp(name, "b") == 0) {
    menu();
    return;
}
```

However, this is poor design since you are using recursion and using up stack for no reason.  You could use `goto`:

```
void menu() {
    char name[MAXNAME];
    float a;
    char c;

menu_prompt:
    cout << "n\tnew transaction\n";
    cout << "v\tview all transactions\n\n";

    c = getchar();
    flushbuf();
    switch (c) {
    case 'N':
    case 'n':{
        cout << "What is the name? (press 'b' to go back to the menu)\n";
        fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin);
        replaceTrailingNl(name);

        if (strcasecmp(name, "b") == 0)
            goto menu_prompt;
```

Generally, though, you would use an outer loop for input.  Then you would use `continue` and `break` depending on whether you want the user to try again or not, respectively.